Mod Header is not working in latest chromium browser selenium with java (ModHeader - Modify HTTP headers" was turned off)
While running and uploading crx file using selenium java with chromium browser with latest verion we are getting this. But i need to manually click Manage exenstion and i need to enable it
Can we please help us to reslove this. This is blocker for our testing with latest chromium version
This is working in Chromium 128.0.6576.0 and not working in later version 129.0.6631.0
sample code:
else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chromium")){
        String chromiumPath = detectChromiumPath();
        Path currentRelativePath = null;
        if (chromiumPath == null) {
          System.err.println("Chromium browser not found. Install Chromium browser");
          System.exit(1);
          return null;
        }
          WebDriverManager.chromiumdriver().clearDriverCache().setup();
          WebDriverManager.chromiumdriver().clearResolutionCache().setup();
        if ((featureValue != null && !featureValue.trim().isEmpty()) || (cellValue !=null && !cellValue.trim().isEmpty())) {
           currentRelativePath = Paths.get("modheader.crx");
        }
          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

        options.setBinary(chromiumPath);
        if(ReUsableMethods.getEnvValue("LOCALTESTING") != null
                && ReUsableMethods.getEnvValue("LOCALTESTING").equalsIgnoreCase("enabled")  ){
          options.addArguments("--headless=new", "--window-size=1920,1200", "--ignore-certificate-errors", "--disable-gpu");
        }
        if ((featureValue != null && !featureValue.trim().isEmpty()) || (cellValue !=null && !cellValue.trim().isEmpty())) {
          options.addExtensions(new File(currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString()));
        }
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        if((featureValue != null && !featureValue.trim().isEmpty()) && (cellValue !=null && !cellValue.trim().isEmpty())){
          driver.get("https://webdriver.modheader.com/add?x-feature="+featureValue+"&x-service-type=custom&x-cell-selector="+cellValue);
          new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(500)).until(ExpectedConditions.titleIs("Done"));
        } else if (featureValue != null && !featureValue.trim().isEmpty()) {
          driver.get("https://webdriver.modheader.com/add?x-feature="+featureValue+"&x-service-type=custom");
          new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(500)).until(ExpectedConditions.titleIs("Done"));
        }
        else if (cellValue !=null && !cellValue.trim().isEmpty()) {
          driver.get("https://webdriver.modheader.com/add?x-cell-selector="+cellValue);
          new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(500)).until(ExpectedConditions.titleIs("Done"));
        }
        }
    }
    return driver;
  }

Docs for modHeaders: https://modheader.com/docs/advanced/selenium-webdriver
I need use this extension without having chromium issue. is there is a way to use enable the extension using selenium ? if there i can use that

Switching from Chrome for Testing to Chrome Stable worked for me for 130.0.6723.117
